# PHP-DI: Routes and optional segments

Tags: php, php-di

I am using PHP-DI with the Slim framework. In Slim you make a route segment optional by putting brackets around it. Now that I have set up PHP-DI when I leave out the optional route segment, I get this error:

```
Type: Invoker\Exception\NotEnoughParametersException
Message: Unable to invoke the callable because no value was given for parameter 1 ($limit)
```

Here is my route:

```
$app->get('/api2/products[/{limit}]', ['\App\Controllers\SampleProductController', 'show']);
```

I can't find anything in the PHP-DI docs that talk about the optional part, just how to get the value of a named segment.

Comment: What is the signature for the method `\App\Controllers\SampleProductController::show` ?

Comment: public function show($limit = 10, Request $request, Response $response)

Comment: The way you've written that method makes the `$limit` look optional but it really is not as there is no way to invoke the function and omit the `$limit`

Comment: I don't think that method signature is valid. Aren't optional parameters supposed to be last in the list?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default Look at example #5

Comment: Thanks for the link, I moved the limit var to the right side and it works. Interesting that the PHP-DI docs show the var for the named segment on the left end of the signature. http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/slim.html#request-attribute-injection

Comment: @dstefani It will probably set $name to null if it's omitted in the URL.

Comment: It still looks like PHP-DI removes the optional segments functionality that Slim offers. I hope I'm wrong, this is a porwerful tool. https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders

Comment: dstefani & @bassxzero thanks for the details, I confirm this is a bug. I added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP-DI author here. This is a bug :)

This is something I fixed not so long ago here: [#521](https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/pull/521/files) But it seems I didn't apply the same logic everywhere (for example in the Invoker package, which is used by all the framework integrations).

I have opened [#562](https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/issues/562) to track this bug, have a look at it for more information.

In the meantime as a workaround you can indeed move the parameter to the end of the method as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you offer this functionality in your library if PHP doesn't?

Comment: @bassxzero I asked myself the same question too :) I guess because people would expect it to work so why not. But this is a bit confusing as we can see.